# Influxdb : CSV import problem, missing values

Tags: csv, influxdb, telegraf

This is my first post on Stack OverFlow and I hope to do it properly.

I'm new to influxdb and telegraf, but as part of a project, I want to import metrics, which come from network equipment and are exported by a network manager via .csv file to influxdb.

I get:

- @IP :

  - 2020-05-YY :

    - CSV1
    - CSV2
  - 2020-05-ZZ

    - ...

The structure of the csv file is as follows:
TimeStamp, NetworkElement_Name, Typeofmeasurement, [depends on the measurement, but in the following example it will be the memory of each card.]

Here is an example :

```
TimeStamp,NetworkElement_Name,Typeofmeasurement,Object,memAbsoluteUsage
2020-05-05T20:00:00+02:00,router1,CPU/Memory Usage,card1,1075
2020-05-05T20:00:00+02:00,router1,CPU/Memory Usage,card2,832
```

This file exists twice for the same timestamp but with a different "NetworkElement_Name", "Object" and value.

As far as telegraf is concerned, I created a ".conf" file, for each imported CSV, as follows :

```
[[inputs.file]]
  files = ["/metric/data/data/clean_data/**/**/router_cpuMemUsage.csv"]
  data_format = "csv"
  csv_header_row_count = 1
  csv_skip_rows = 0
  csv_skip_columns = 0
  csv_delimiter = ","
  csv_column_types = ["string","string","string","string","int"]
  csv_measurement_column = "Typeofmeasurement"
  csv_timestamp_column = "TimeStamp"
  csv_timestamp_format = "2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00"

[[outputs.influxdb]]
  database = "router Metrics"
```

And the data seems  imported... but, I realize that some values are missing...

I have difficulty understanding / explaining the problem.
But I can't get all the values recorded at a specific time.
the return request :

```
> SELECT * FROM "CPU/Memory Usage" WHERE "NE Name" =~ /router1/ ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 5
name: CPU/Memory Usage
time                 NE Name    Object ID    Object Type      Time Stamp                     memUsage 
----                 -------    ---------    -----------      ----------                    ---------- 
2020-05-07T06:45:00Z router1    card1    CPU/Memory Usage   2020-05-07T08:45:00+02:00           1075             
2020-05-07T06:30:00Z router1    card1    CPU/Memory Usage   2020-05-07T08:30:00+02:00           1075             
2020-05-07T06:15:00Z router1    card1    CPU/Memory Usage   2020-05-07T08:15:00+02:00           1075             
2020-05-07T06:00:00Z router1    card1    CPU/Memory Usage   2020-05-07T08:00:00+02:00           1075             
2020-05-07T05:45:00Z router1    card1    CPU/Memory Usage   2020-05-07T07:45:00+02:00           1075
```

I have only the information of the card 1, not the one of the 2 and if I remove the "WHERE" clause, for the same "TIMESTAMP", I don't have all the information, I miss the information on the router 2.

The values present for one router at a given "TIMESTAMP" will not be present for the other.

I have trouble understanding where the problem can be prevented.

If one of you has an idea :)

Comment: The problem is the same timestamp. You would need a unique tag to ensure that no data is overwritten within the database. Alternatively you can also increase the timestamp by one nanosecond since influxdb allows nanosecond precision.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I tried to add milliseconds, but I have the same problem. (I'm only working with 1 device at the moment, I'll leave creating databases per device later).

However, no problem if I switch to the second.

did I forget something about telegraf / influxdb to make it read the TimeStamp correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't have to configure anything on the influxdb side. Did you also alter the `timestamp_format` in your config file? In the config you posted initially, changes in milliseconds are not recognized.

Comment: yes, new "csv_timestamp_format" : 2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000-07:00. I have chosen, for the moment, to add 1 millisecond per line of my CSV. 
In the database, only the "TimeStamp": .000001 are added. I didn't check in all the files, but it corresponds to the first line of the files. No problem if I add 1 second.

Comment: Can you try and convert the timestamp in the csv to Unix timestamp and then try insertion again? I am not quite sure what is going on here. Currently unable to run tests on my own...

Comment: Same problem, it only adds the first values of each file: 1588862700000 and not the 1588862700001, 1588862700002, etc...
I changed the timestamp format to : "unix_ms"

Comment: I have never used the `csv_column_type`, never needed it. Maybe that messes with your timestamp? Also the `timestamp_column` shouldn't appear as a seperate field when querying the database.

Comment: Same problem removing the "csv_column_type" field.
The difference between the "Time Stamp" field and the "time" field is the timezone.
The csv files arrive with a +2:00 and influx shows me the Time in UTC: "Z".